# How to add and edit time in a textctrl in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am developing a GUI using wxpython where i need a textctrl which selects the time .I tried with TimePickerCtrl but failed to fetch the time into the textctrl. It would be great if anyone shares a good example code which adds a time to a textctrl and can be edit the textctrl at any time.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should update the question with your attempt with `TimePickerCtrl` so that we can fix your attempt instead of writing code for you.

Comment: Is there any other than TimePickerCtrl to add the time to a textctrl or spinctrl??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you even look at the wxPython demo? It shows 3 different ways to create the picker control:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.masked as masked

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # 12-hour format
        text1 = wx.StaticText( self, -1, "12-hour format:", size=(150,-1))
        self.time12 = masked.TimeCtrl( self, -1, name="12 hour control" )
        h = self.time12.GetSize().height
        spin1 = wx.SpinButton( 
                  self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (-1,h), wx.SP_VERTICAL )
        self.time12.BindSpinButton( spin1 )
        self.addWidgets([text1, self.time12, spin1])
        # 24-hour format
        text2 = wx.StaticText( self, -1, "24-hour format:")
        spin2 = wx.SpinButton(
                  self, -1, wx.DefaultPosition, (-1,h), wx.SP_VERTICAL )
        self.time24 = masked.TimeCtrl(
                        self, -1, name="24 hour control", fmt24hr=True,
                        spinButton = spin2
                        )
        self.addWidgets([text2, self.time24, spin2])
        # No seconds\nor spin button
        text3 = wx.StaticText( self, -1, "No seconds\nor spin button:")
        self.spinless_ctrl = masked.TimeCtrl(
                                self, -1, name="spinless control",
                                display_seconds = False
                                )
        self.addWidgets([text3, self.spinless_ctrl])
        # set sizer
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

    def addWidgets(self, widgets):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        for widget in widgets:
            if isinstance(widget, wx.StaticText):
                sizer.Add(widget, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5),
            else:
                sizer.Add(widget, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(sizer)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Spinner Demo")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    app = wx.App(False)
    f = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. I had a look at wxpython demo. I used self.Time=TimeCtrl(self.panel, id = -1,value = '00:00:00',pos=(430,108),size = wx.DefaultSize,style = wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB,validator = wx.DefaultValidator,name = "time",format = 'HHMMSS',fmt24hr = False,displaySeconds = True,spinButton = None,min = None,max = None,limited = None,oob_color = "Yellow") and it worked for me.